# Remove product-category slug plugin works with 1 subcategroy not with 2

Tags: plugins

I am using Remove product-category slug plugin works with 1 subcategroy not with 2.
Like:

```
www.domain.com/europe/netherlands/amsterdam (doesn't work)
www.domain.com/product-categorie/europe/netherlands/amsterdam (work)
www.domain.com/europe/netherlands           (work)
www.domain.com/product-categorie/europe/netherlands           (work)
```

Plugincode:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Remove product-category slug
Plugin URI: https://timersys.com/
Description: Check if url slug matches a woocommerce product category and use it instead
Version: 0.1
Author: Timersys
License: GPLv2 or later
*/
add_filter('request', function( $vars ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( ! empty( $vars['pagename'] ) || ! empty( $vars['category_name'] ) || ! empty( $vars['name'] ) || ! empty( $vars['attachment'] ) ) {
        $slug = ! empty( $vars['pagename'] ) ? $vars['pagename'] : ( ! empty( $vars['name'] ) ? $vars['name'] : ( !empty( $vars['category_name'] ) ? $vars['category_name'] : $vars['attachment'] ) );
        $exists = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT t.term_id FROM $wpdb->terms t LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND t.slug = %s" ,array( $slug )));
        if( $exists ){
            $old_vars = $vars;
            $vars = array('product_cat' => $slug );
            if ( !empty( $old_vars['paged'] ) || !empty( $old_vars['page'] ) )
                $vars['paged'] = ! empty( $old_vars['paged'] ) ? $old_vars['paged'] : $old_vars['page'];
            if ( !empty( $old_vars['orderby'] ) )
                $vars['orderby'] = $old_vars['orderby'];
            if ( !empty( $old_vars['order'] ) )
                $vars['order'] = $old_vars['order'];
        }
    }
    return $vars;
});
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my setup i know there are max 3 params, so this is my solution

```
add_filter('request', function( $vars ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if(isset($vars['error'])){
        $lastVar = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $vars['attachment'] = $lastVar;
    }
    ........rest off code........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone still search for this problem... changing the permalink setting for posts to "Article Name" (site.com/name-article) fixed the problem for me.

I also use this code in function.php:

```
add_filter('request', function( $vars ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if(isset($vars['error'])){
        $lastVar = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $vars['attachment'] = $lastVar;
    }
   if( ! empty( $vars['pagename'] ) || ! empty( $vars['category_name'] ) || ! empty( $vars['name'] ) || ! empty( $vars['attachment'] ) ) {
      $slug = ! empty( $vars['pagename'] ) ? $vars['pagename'] : ( ! empty( $vars['name'] ) ? $vars['name'] : ( !empty( $vars['category_name'] ) ? $vars['category_name'] : $vars['attachment'] ) );
      $exists = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT t.term_id FROM $wpdb->terms t LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND t.slug = %s" ,array( $slug )));
      if( $exists ){
         $old_vars = $vars;
         $vars = array('product_cat' => $slug );
         if ( !empty( $old_vars['paged'] ) || !empty( $old_vars['page'] ) )
            $vars['paged'] = ! empty( $old_vars['paged'] ) ? $old_vars['paged'] : $old_vars['page'];
         if ( !empty( $old_vars['orderby'] ) )
            $vars['orderby'] = $old_vars['orderby'];
         if ( !empty( $old_vars['order'] ) )
            $vars['order'] = $old_vars['order']; 
      }
   }
   return $vars;
});

add_filter('term_link', 'term_link_filter', 10, 3);
function term_link_filter( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    $url=str_replace("/./","/",$url);
     return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Bas's expansion with $vars['error'], but in my case there wasn't a $vars['error'] available. So I updated that piece of code to this:

```
    if (empty($vars) || isset($vars['error'])) {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
            $is_product_cat = str_contains($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'product_cat');
            if ($is_product_cat) {
                $lastVar = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                $vars['attachment'] = $lastVar;
            }
        }
    }
```

?taxonomy=product_cat is part of the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] when you're actually targeting a product cat to redirect. So that's a safe var to check.

This results in the full snippet below:

```
/**
 * Strip "product-category" from the URLS.
 * @note https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447175/woocommerce-how-to-remove-product-product-category-from-urls
 * @updates Added bits from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258053/remove-product-category-slug-plugin-works-with-1-subcategroy-not-with-2/258085#258085
 */
add_filter('request', function ($vars) {
    global $wpdb;
    
    if (empty($vars) || isset($vars['error'])) {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
            $is_product_cat = str_contains($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'product_cat');
            if ($is_product_cat) {
                $lastVar = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                $vars['attachment'] = $lastVar;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!empty($vars['pagename']) || !empty($vars['category_name']) || !empty($vars['name']) || !empty($vars['attachment'])) {
        $slug = !empty($vars['pagename']) ? $vars['pagename'] : (!empty($vars['name']) ? $vars['name'] : (!empty($vars['category_name']) ? $vars['category_name'] : $vars['attachment']));
        $slug_array = explode('/', $slug);
        $slug = array_values(array_slice($slug_array, -1))[0];
        $exists = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT t.term_id FROM $wpdb->terms t LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND t.slug = %s",
            array($slug)));
        if ($exists) {
            $old_vars = $vars;
            $vars = array('product_cat' => $slug);
            if (!empty($old_vars['paged']) || !empty($old_vars['page'])) {
                $vars['paged'] = !empty($old_vars['paged']) ? $old_vars['paged'] : $old_vars['page'];
            }
            if (!empty($old_vars['orderby'])) {
                $vars['orderby'] = $old_vars['orderby'];
            }
            if (!empty($old_vars['order'])) {
                $vars['order'] = $old_vars['order'];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $vars;
});
```

I didn't need the term_link filter myself.